# Consider a random variable X having the following PDF...

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I have to calculate the value of $c$ that makes this a legit PDF but I only know how to do it when it only has one function (set equal $1$ , integrate, solve for $c$). How do I calculate it for these two functions? I'm totally lost!

$$ f(x)  =   \begin{cases} c & \text{for}\ 0<x<2 \\ 2c & \text{for}\ 5<x<10, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just integrate piecewise:

$$\int f(x) \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^2 c \text{d}x + \int_5^{10} 2c \text{d}x = 2c+10c=12c.$$

So take $c= \frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think it was going to be that simple! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question :)

Comment: No problem -- feel free to click the green checkmark if this helped you! Also just a note, this isn't "two functions" per se; it's just a step function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function

Comment: I absolutely will! There's a timer apparently. Also thanks for the link, knowing what to actually call this is a definite improvement for whenever I need help on something similar in the future :D